# My Ajax callback is not working as I expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I thought I knew how this worked - obviously not.

I'm not able to return a value gotten from a jQuery Ajax request.

This is my code:

```
  function initForm() {
    prefix = getPrefix(country_id);
    alert(prefix); // <-- prefix is empty
  }


  // Get prefix
  function getPrefix(country_id) {
    var prefix = '';

    jQuery.ajax({
      url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery.php",
      data: {instance: 'getPrefix', country_id : country_id},
      success: (function(data) {
          prefix = data.prefix;
          alert(prefix) // <--- This alerts correct value
      }),
      dataType: 'json'
    });

    return prefix; // <-- This value is not set
  }
```

How do I use callback correctly to set the `prefix` variable inside the `jQuery.ajax` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous behaviour of your Ajax request. The `getPrefix()` function will have returned before the Ajax request receives its response. You should pass the callback function to the `getPrefix(country_id)` function, something like:

```
function getPrefix(country_id, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery.php",
      data: {instance: 'getPrefix', country_id : country_id},
      success: (function(data) {
          callback.call(null, data.prefix);
      }),
      dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

And then call as follows:

```
function initForm() {
    getPrefix(country_id, function (prefix) {
        // 'prefix' is now available
    });
}
```

Comment: brilliant. I've done this before but forgotten how. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The value of prefix is not being set because it is returned before the ajax post gets a response and the callback is triggered.

Instead, try

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery.php",
  data: {instance: 'getPrefix', country_id : country_id},
  success: (function(data) {
      prefix = data.prefix;
      alert(prefix) // <--- This alerts correct value
      return prefix;
    }),
    dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that and that wasn't working. See jakeclarkson answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you. Since Ajax calls are asynchronous, you need to have a callback to set the prefix variable.

```
function initForm() { 
   getPrefix(country_id); 
} 



function getPrefix(country_id) { 
var _this=this;

jQuery.ajax({ 
  url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery.php", 
  data: {instance: 'getPrefix', country_id : country_id}, 
  success: (function(data) { 
_this.setPrefix(data.prefix);       }), 
  dataType: 'json' 
});
```

}

```
function setPrefix(prefixData){
prefix = prefixData;
      alret(prefix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, while not recommended is to use to synchronized version.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery.php",
  data: {instance: 'getPrefix', country_id : country_id},
  success: (function(data) {
      prefix = data.prefix;
      alert(prefix) // <--- This alerts correct value
  }),
  async:false,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

But I would concur with the previous answers.